# Logging outgoing connections as they happen

Tags: tcp, netstat

Is there a way to log to file all the outgoing connections that a process creates? I am aware of `netstat` but that seems to be more of a snapshot of a point in time rather than something that runs and logs information over a period.

I only need the IP or hostname, port and the process making the connection.

Comment: Well, you could do something like `watch -n 2 netstat` in the meantime, but that's not a proper solution, is it.

Comment: [This thread][1] should answer your question


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/34782/with-linux-iptables-is-it-possible-to-log-the-process-command-name-that-initiat

Comment: See also [How to find out which file is currently written by a process](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31367) for file accesses

Answer (score 16):

On Linux, you can set up the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) to log every attempt to establish a network connection. For information about the audit subsystem, read the [`auditctl` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/auditctl.8.html) or [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) or [other examples on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bauditctl). Install your distribution's `auditd` package if necessary, then

```
auditctl -A exit,always -S connect
```

The logs are in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` on all the distributions that I know of. You can also [search them](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Audit_framework#Search_the_logs) with `ausearch`.

Comment: I needed to identify which process was making an outgoing connection. This did it instantly. To avoid flooding the logs, remove the rule afterward: `auditctl -d exit,always -S connect`

Comment: How do I inspect the logs?

Comment: @luckydonald `less /var/log/audit/audit.log`

Comment: This seems to log a huge amount of data, though having tried a `curl` - the ip address was NOT logged in the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file.

Comment: The IP address and port are part of the saddr field. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102926/how-to-interpret-the-saddr-field-of-an-audit-log

Comment: seems like to capture outgoing connection activities, `-F filetype=socket` is needed per manpage.  but another [thread](https://linux-audit.redhat.narkive.com/fqyxF7vx/filtering-connect-syscalls-for-af-inet-only) said it doesn't work.  Any idea how to just audit outgoing connection activities?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you're able to install a custom kernel, you should have a look at [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/). There are plenty of [examples](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/) how to trace network activity.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can use [`ip_conntrack`](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html) to accomplish this.  It's a connection tracking module, used normally to monitor connections for oddly behaving protocols (like FTP) to be managed by a firewall/NAT box.

```
modprobe ip_conntrack
cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack
```

You can grep the pseudo-file to see established connections,
and further grep the source IP to see when it originates from your box.

Comment: The question may not be necessarily Linux-centric.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using `tcpdump` on the outbound interface looking at the outbound `SYN` requests.

If you feel really adventurous you could make utilities like: `strace` or `truss` report all `connect` system calls while tracing the execution of the program but this is a bit more dangerous and has drawbacks when dealing with multithreaded processes.