# How to interpret the "saddr" field of an audit log?

Tags: audit

I'm trying to log the parameter of `connect`, so I added one rule with `auditctl`.

Now in audit.log I get lines like this:

> type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(1385638181.866:89758729): saddr=hex string

So how should I interpret the target address from the hex string (I'm not sure what is stored in that hex string)?

Comment: If the string doesn't change then e.g: `echo "type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(1385638181.866:89758729): saddr=hex string" | awk -F= '/saddr/{print $NF}'`  would get the desired result.

Comment: @val0x00ff Then how do I know the address it connects to ..?

Comment: @warl0ck - can you show what that string looks like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this Perl script, [parse-audit-log.pl](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/viewfile/LinuxSupport/IDSNetConnectionLogger?rev=1.1;filename=parse-audit-log.pl), that shows a function that can parse that string as follows:

```
sub parse_saddr
{
    my $sockfd = $_[0];
    my $saddr = $_[1];
    # 0 - sys_bind(), 1 - sys_connect(), 2 - sys_accept()
    my $action = $_[2];

    ($f1, $f2, $p1, $p2, @addr) = unpack("A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2", $saddr);
    $family = hex2dec($f1) + 256 * hex2dec($f2);
    $port = 256 * hex2dec($p1) + hex2dec($p2);
    $ip1 = hex2dec($addr[0]);
    $ip2 = hex2dec($addr[1]);
    $ip3 = hex2dec($addr[2]);
    $ip4 = hex2dec($addr[3]);
    #print "$saddr\n";
    if ($family eq 2) { #&& $ip1 ne 0) {
        my $dst_addr = "$ip1.$ip2.$ip3.$ip4:$port";
#       print "family=$family $dst_addr\n\n";
        # todo: avoid code duplication
        if ($action eq 0) {
            $sockfd_hash{ $sockfd } = $dst_addr;
        } elsif ($action eq 1) {
            my $src_addr;
            if (exists $sockfd_hash{ $sockfd }) {
                $src_addr = $sockfd_hash{ $sockfd };
            } else {
                $src_addr = "x.x.x.x:x";
            }
            print "$src_addr -> $dst_addr\n";
        } elsif ($action eq 2) {
            my $src_addr;
            if (exists $sockfd_hash{ $sockfd }) {
                $src_addr = $sockfd_hash{ $sockfd };
            } else {
                $src_addr = "x.x.x.x:x";
            }
            print "$dst_addr <- $src_addr\n";
        } else {
            print "unknown action\n";
        }
    } elsif ($family eq 1) {
        $tmp1 = 0;
        ($tmp1, $tmp2) = unpack("A4A*", $saddr);
        my $file = pack("H*", $tmp2);
#       print "family=$family file=$file\n";
    } else {
#       print "$saddr\n";
    }
}
```

This script was part of this [TWiki page on the CERN website](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LinuxSupport/WebHome), under [LinuxSupport](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LinuxSupport/LinuxSupportInternals). The page titled: [IDSNetConnectionLogger](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LinuxSupport/IDSNetConnectionLogger) contains 2 files of interest. One the script I mentioned above, [parse-audit-log.pl](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/pub/LinuxSupport/IDSNetConnectionLogger/parse-audit-log.pl), and the other is a sample [audit.log](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/pub/LinuxSupport/IDSNetConnectionLogger/audit.log) file.

#### Running the script

If you download those 2 files you'll notice this is what you're asking about.

#### Examples

```
$ ./parse-audit-log.pl -l audit.log 
x.x.x.x:x -> 0.0.0.0:22
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.32.52:22
137.138.32.52:22 <- x.x.x.x:x
x.x.x.x:x -> 0.0.0.0:22
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.32.52:0
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.128.158:88
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.128.148:750
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.128.158:88
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.32.52:0
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.16.5:53
x.x.x.x:x -> 137.138.128.158:88
x.x.x.x:x -> 127.0.0.1:6010
```

#### Pulling out the parser logic

We can kind of condense the above so that it's a `saddr` parser only. Here's my stripped down version.

```
$ cat parse_saddr.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Getopt::Std module from the perl package
use Getopt::Std;

my %Options;
getopt('s', \%Options);

if (defined($Options{'s'})) {
    $saddr = $Options{'s'};
} else {
    print "saddr not given\n";
    exit(-1);
}

sub hex2dec($) { return hex $_[0] }

sub parse_saddr
{
    my $saddr = $_[0];

    ($f1, $f2, $p1, $p2, @addr) = unpack("A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2", $saddr);
    $family = hex2dec($f1) + 256 * hex2dec($f2);
    $port = 256 * hex2dec($p1) + hex2dec($p2);
    $ip1 = hex2dec($addr[0]);
    $ip2 = hex2dec($addr[1]);
    $ip3 = hex2dec($addr[2]);
    $ip4 = hex2dec($addr[3]);
    #print "$saddr\n";
    if ($family eq 2) { #&& $ip1 ne 0) {
        my $dst_addr = "$ip1.$ip2.$ip3.$ip4:$port";
        print "family=$family $dst_addr\n\n";
    } elsif ($family eq 1) {
        $tmp1 = 0;
        ($tmp1, $tmp2) = unpack("A4A*", $saddr);
        my $file = pack("H*", $tmp2);
        print "family=$family file=$file\n";
    } else {
        print "$saddr\n";
    }
}

&parse_saddr($saddr);
```

#### Sample run of saddr parser scrip

We can run it like so:

```
$ ./parse_saddr.pl -s 02000035898A1005000000000000000030BED20858D83A0010000000
family=2 137.138.16.5:53
```

You could then use a command like this to parse all the `saddr=..` lines from the `audit.log` file mentioned above:

```
$ for i in $(grep saddr audit.log | cut -d"=" -f4);do echo $i; \
    ./parse_saddr.pl -s $i;done | less
```

The above is hacked together so it doesn't handle the family=1 types of `saddr`. You'd have to dig in more, but this gives you a rough start as to how to deal with all this.

#### Example output

```
$ for i in $(grep saddr audit.log | cut -d"=" -f4);do echo $i; \
    ./parse_saddr.pl -s $i;done | less
...
01002F6465762F6C6F67000000000000
family=1 file=/dev/log^@^@^@^@^@^@
...

02000035898A10050000000000000000726E2E6368009A0900000000
family=2 137.138.16.5:53

...
02000058898A809E0000000000000000
family=2 137.138.128.158:88

...
020002EE898A80940000000000000000
family=2 137.138.128.148:750

...
0200177A7F0000010000000000000000
family=2 127.0.0.1:6010

...
```

#### Perl's pack/unpack functions

These are very powerful functions once you understand how they work. If you've never used them before then I'd take a look at the tutorial, [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html).

The idea behind these functions is that they take data in and use a template to return that data using the the template as a structure of how the data should be organized.

Again here's a simple Perl script that shows the unpacking of the `saddr`.

```
$ cat unpack.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$saddr = "02000035898A1005000000000000000030BED20858D83A0010000000";
($f1, $f2, $p1, $p2, @addr) = unpack("A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2", $saddr);

printf "org string: $saddr\n";
printf "org values==> f1: %s f2: %s p1: %s p2: %s addr: %s\n",
    $f1,$f2,$p1,$p2,join("",@addr);
printf "new values==> f1: %2s f2: %2s p1: %2s p2: %2s addr: %s.%s.%s.%s\n\n", 
    hex($f1),hex($f2),hex($p1),hex($p2),hex($addr[0]),hex($addr[1]),hex($addr[2]),hex($addr[3]);
```

Which produces this:

```
$ ./unpack.pl 
org string: 02000035898A1005000000000000000030BED20858D83A0010000000
org values==> f1: 02 f2: 00 p1: 00 p2: 35 addr: 898A1005
new values==> f1:  2 f2:  0 p1:  0 p2: 53 addr: 137.138.16.5
```

Here we're taking the data that's contained in `$saddr` and calling `unpack()` telling the function to take the data 2 bytes at a time (A2). Do this 10 times. The first 4 `A2` blocks, which are really just 2 characters apiece, are stored in the variables: `$f1`, `$f2`, `$p1`, `$p2`. The remaining characters are stored in the array `@addr`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-i` option to `ausearch`

> **-i, --interpret**
>   Interpret  numeric  entities into text. For example, uid is converted to account name. The conversion is done using the current resources of the machine where the search is
>   being run. If you have renamed the accounts, or don't have the same accounts on your machine, you could get misleading results.

That also decodes the `saddr`s in `type=SOCKADDR` entries.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new logging option since `auditd` 2.6 to enabled enriched logs.

In /etc/audit/auditd.conf change log_format to `ENRICHED`:

```
log_format = ENRICHED
```

This will output fields with meaningful names for various fields including the users and groups and system calls. The capitalized fields are the enriched fields. `SOCKADDR` events have the decoded IP, port or filename of the socket.

Examples:

> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1583352267.747:333333): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=19eed30 a1=19e7360 a2=19e6ff0 a3=7ffce315f1e0 items=2 ppid=28317 pid=30555 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=1681 comm="tail" exe="/usr/bin/tail" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="EXECVE" ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=execve AUID="root" UID="root" GID="root" EUID="root" SUID="root" FSUID="root" EGID="root" SGID="root" FSGID="root"
>
> type=SOCKADDR msg=audit(1583352273.046:333334): saddr=0200028F000000000000000000000000SADDR={ fam=inet laddr=0.0.0.0 lport=655 }

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2016-June/msg00053.html

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone found this and was looking for a python saddr parsing function...

```
def parse_saddr(saddr):
    if len(saddr) >= 16 and saddr.startswith('0200'):
        port, ipaddr = struct.unpack('>HL', binascii.unhexlify(saddr[4:16]))
        ip_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>L', ipaddr))

        print('{}:{}'.format(ip_addr, str(port)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following to achieve this in powershell

```
function parseSocketAddr {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$Saddr
    )
    begin {
        $re = [regex]"^(?<socket>(?:02|0A)00)(?<port>[a-fA-F0-9]{4})(?<ip>[a-fA-F0-9]{8})(?<remainder>[a-fA-F0-9]+)$"
    }
    process {
        $socket, $port, $ip, $remainder = $re.Match($saddr).groups.Where({$_.Name -ne '0'}).value
        $ipRev = ($ip -split "(\w{2})").Where({$_ -ne ""})[4..0] -join ""
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            type = $socket
            IPAddress = ([IPAddress][convert]::ToInt64($ip,16)).IPAddressToString
            Port = [convert]::ToInt32($port,16)
            Remainder = $remainder
        }
    }
}
```